# how to modify a df based on another df boolean values?

Tags: python, pandas

I got 2 DataFrames. df1 (booleans) and df2 (integers). I can't figure out how to modify df2 based on df1.

Goal: To modify df2 and change values to 100 if False in df1. If True don't change.

```
df1
date         x     y      w      z 
2017-02-02  True  False  True   True
2017-02-03  False True   True   True


df2
date         x    y    w   z 
2017-02-02   1    2    3   4
2017-02-03   2    4    1   3
```

Expectation

```
df2
date         x    y    w   z 
2017-02-02   1   100   3   4
2017-02-03   100  4    1   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable by a simple conditional statement

`df2[df1==False] = 100`

Comment: Oh didn't know you could simply add another df in the []. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I did not know that until I searched and tried different things. I am not being sarcastic or rude. Just saying

Answer (score 0):

#### [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), ensuring you choose only relevant columns (i.e. ignoring the first columns). There's usually *never* a need to explicitly check `== False` or `== True` with Pandas.

```
df2.iloc[:, 1:] = df2.iloc[:, 1:].where(df1.iloc[:, 1:], 100)

print(df2)

         date    x    y  w  z
0  2017-02-02    1  100  3  4
1  2017-02-03  100    4  1  3
```